# Odoo - CRM workflow: convert opportunity into customer

Tags: crm, odoo-9

In Odoo 9, is it possible to convert an opportunity into a customer, similarly to converting a lead into an opportunity ? 
As long as the opportunity is not "won" I do not want to link it to a customer, as it becomes a customer only after signing the contract. But then, when the opportunity is won, I am stuck as I cannot create a new customer from the opportunity view.

I am looking for the right workflow to achieve that goal. I tried to working only with leads, and convert the lead to an opportunity related to a new customer as soon as the lead signs the contract (and is thus "won"). This works, but then I am losing all functionalities of opportunities (such as planning meetings).

Any advice on how to use leads-opportunities-customers correctly in my use case?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is the original Odoo workflow as I bent it a lot, but when converting lead to opportunity I create a `res_partner` instance in stage Prospect. Then if opportunity is won, the partner's stage changes to Customer. 
For this purpose I use table `res_partner_stage` with stages: *Inactive* (former customer), *Prospect* (soon-to-be customer) and *Customer* (active customer).